# How to get the id of a VM in azure where power state is running and a specific tag is null?

Tags: azure, azure-cli, jmespath

So I am trying to get the ID of all VMs across all subscriptions and regions, where a specific tag is null. For this I am using the following command

```sh
az vm list -d --query '[?!not_null(tags.run)]|[].id'
```

**Please note: I want to get the ids only if the tag doesn't exist**

Here notice I need to use single quotes to cover the query as I am using the '!' operator to inverse the `not_null()` function. If I were to use double quotes bash will throw an `event not found` error.

So now the problem arises when I also want to add a condition to check the current state of the VM and return id only if it is running and tag doesn't exist.

```sh
az vm list -d --query '[?!not_null(tags.run)] | [?powerState=="VM running"].id'
```

Here I have to wrap `VM running` in double quotes and this gives me an empty output as the string is not being matched because the query expects single quotes like so -

```
"[?powerState=='VM running'].id"
```

Could someone help me with a workaround for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [raw string literals](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#raw-string-literals) for *VM running* string. You just have to surround your string with a back tick and a double quote.

```
az vm list -d  --query '[?!not_null(tags.run)]|[?powerState==`"VM running"`].id'
```